Prohibit author from closing their own pull request on GitHub
Someone sent me a pull request on GitHub. I asked for changes to the functionality they had implemented. Then they closed the pull request and opened another one for the same fork:branch. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, i.e. only allow the maintainers to close pull requests that are sent in.

I'd like to know the same. Haven't found any tips on how to do it. There's a "closed" trigger for pull requests, but I would have to check whether triggering this will prevent closing; it will probably not, since it's triggered after closing.
